# Alpha removal with ImageMagick is bad but only with a white background

Tags: imagemagick, image-manipulation

I'm getting surprising (to me) variations in antialiasing quality when converting a PDF (with black text on white only) to a PNG and removing transparency with ImageMagick (version 6.7.7.10 from Ubuntu 14.04).

My sample input file is the result of running `pdflatex` on

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\begin{document}
Hello, world!
\end{document}
```

At 300 dpi, the result is horrible (that's with a white background, adding `-background \#ffffff` or `-background white` produces visually indistinguishable output):

```
convert -density 300 -alpha remove -alpha off a.pdf 300-white.png
```

[image: -density 300]

There's some anti-aliasing, but not very good, and some lines (such as the horizontal stroked on the `e`) have completely disappeared.

Choosing any color other than white produces a decent result.

```
convert -density 300 -background \#fffffe -alpha remove -alpha off a.pdf 300-fffffe.png
```

[image: -density 300 -background #fffffe]

Curiously, the rendering is better at low resolutions (while still not ideal) — at least the text is readable.

```
convert -density 100 -alpha remove -alpha off a.pdf 90-white.png
```

[image: -density 100]

At higher resolutions, the rendering is still clearly poor, but at least the lines start to appear.

```
convert -density 750 -alpha remove -alpha off a.pdf a.png
```

[image: -density 750]

- Why is antialiasing so bad for black on white, and perfectly fine with any other background color, even if that background color is visually indistinguishable from white?
- If I set this up as part of an automated process where someone won't be around to visually inspect the result, what parameters do I need to avoid to get good results?

Comment: That's a good question for the ImageMagick mailing list, which was once very active - but there is a forum now: http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/ -- or file a bug report, you have a good case!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is like when background is white, ImageMagick detects that there are only two colors — black and white — and switches to a grayscale mode of PNG, hence the ugly result:

[image]

To limit the ugliness of applying black and white to anti-aliased edges, you can disable anti-aliasing with `+antialias`:

```
convert -density 300 -alpha remove -alpha off +antialias a.pdf 300-white.png
```

[image]

So now, how to prevent using the grayscale [mode of PNG](http://css-ig.net/articles/differents-types-png)? Here it is:

```
convert -density 300 -alpha remove -alpha off a.pdf png24:300-white-24.png
```

[image]